# 500 Internal Server Error with passing wrong parameter in action of struts 2.0

Tags: infinite

my working environment is below 
jsp,struts 2.0,java
And my issue is that
when i fire below url in browser

(1) https://test123.local.com/test123/test.action?id=9

it works fine

but when i fire the same url with updatin 9 to 9'

(2) https://test123.local.com/test123/test.action?id=9'

give me the following exception in console

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
Infinite recursion detected:

and as per checking in FF fireburg tool display me the 500 Internal Server Error.

and body have idea to prevent this type of error, I need to catch this error in exception and want to redirect the users to access restricted page.

Here i mentioned more detail which i had found from my side.

as per the shown in (2)  given url

my struts-admin.xml entry as like below

```
<action name="test" method="test" class="com.os.Environment.TestAction">  
            <interceptor-ref name="customStack">  
            </interceptor-ref>  
            <result>/jsp/user/tested.jsp</result>  
            <result name="passed" type="redirect-action">passed?Id=${Id}</result>  
</action>  
<interceptor-stack name="customStack">  
                <interceptor-ref name="chainStack"/>  
                <interceptor-ref name="myCustomCheck"/>  
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>  
                <interceptor-ref name="exception">  
                    <param name="logEnabled">true</param>  
                    <param name="logLevel">ERROR</param>  
                </interceptor-ref>  
</interceptor-stack>
```

hence first of my customStack interceptor called

below is my custom interceptor code

```
public class myCustomCheck extends AbstractInterceptor  
{  

    private String invoke(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception  
    {  
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();  
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();  
        return invocation.invoke(); //this line throw the exception  
    }  

public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception  
    {  
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();  
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();  
        return invoke(invocation);        
        }  

}
```

i had debugging the above code , and i had  found that my interceptor will not call my "handled" name action and throws the exception as per given below:

Infinite recursion detected: [//test!test, //handled, //handled] - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionChainResult.execute(ActionChainResult.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:348)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)

let me know if you want to other information